# Some issue has been occurring for 2 days and I am unable to solve it in npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I have tried `npm clear cache --force`, removing `node_modules/` and `package-lock.json` and then again `npm install` and then `npm build` and finally `npm run dev`. But unfortunately this failed around 5-6 times.

My Errors:

```
npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0 build: `next build`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0 build script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-25T14_05_46_415Z-debug.log
```

My debug logs:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run-script',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.14
3 info using node@v14.17.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0~prebuild: with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0~build: with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;M:\Amazon-starter-template-nextjs\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\divya\AppData\Local\Programs\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot\bin;C:\Users\divya\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\divya\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0~build: CWD: M:\Amazon-starter-template-nextjs
10 silly lifecycle with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'next build' ]
11 silly lifecycle with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0 build: `next build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd M:\Amazon-starter-template-nextjs
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run-script" "build"
18 verbose node v14.17.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.14
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0 build: `next build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the with-redux-toolkit@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My package.json file:

```json
{
  "name": "with-redux-toolkit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.4",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.5.0",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.2.0",
    "firebase": "^8.6.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "heroicons-react": "^1.4.1",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.2",
    "next": "^11.1.0",
    "next-fonts": "^1.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "7.2.2"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "postcss": "^8.2.15",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: How much memory does your computer have available?

Comment: 4gb ram and 1tb hdd

Answer (score 0):

As the error says itself, this is not a problem with NPM. Only we have to do is

instead of,

```
npm  run build -prod
```

extend the javascript memory by following,

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

Answer (score 0):

npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache
npm run build

(I tried cache clean but not work)